# Negative numbers with time count

Tags: c, shell, unix, time

I wonder why im getting negative values ive tried with multiple datatypes(float , double long double etc) but the result is .. or its negative number or Zero or NA. this is a function to check the medium service time to a costumer in a store, i've only posted the relevant part of the code for the problem. Ty in advance

```
struct timeval timecount[MAX_COSTUMERS+1][2];

long double getMedium(struct timeval x[][2]){
      long double diff;
      int i;
      for(i=1;i<k.clientID;i++){
          diff+= ((x[i][1].tv_usec )*0.0000001 -  (x[i][0].tv_usec)*0.0000001) ) ;
      }

      return diff;
}

void AFUNCTION(){  // Called a bunch of times
       k.clientID++;
       gettimeofday(&timecount[k.clientID][0], NULL);

   // DO A BUNCH OF STUFF


       gettimeofday(&timecount[k.clientID][1], NULL);


}

void main ( ) {

     long double aux;
     aux=getMedia(timecount);
     printf("%LG \n",aux);

}
```

Comment: Should the call to `getMedia` be `getMedium` or is that a different function?  The parentheses do not match in the `diff` accumulation expression, so this is not real code - we could be addressing problems you don;t have if we can see the real code!

Comment: Field `tv_usec` is likely a `long`.  `0.0000001` is certainly a `double`.  So the right side of `diff += ...` may only be done with `double` precision math.  Yet code accumulates with `long double`.    Consider `0.0000001L` for uniform precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least three errors, one ill-advised practice (apart from the use of [global data](http://www.ganssle.com/articles/globals.htm) that is!), and one fundamental design flaw :

- If you want an answer in microseconds, then you need to multiply by 0.000001 not 0.0000001.  Less error prone to simply divide by 1e6.
- You have not used the `tv_sec` member; `tv_usec` will rollover to zero at the start of the second, so if the start time was in the previous second, you may get a negative value - you certainly not get the correct answer.
- Failure to initialise `diff`.
- You should avoid accumulating with floating point operations.  It is unnecessary and will accumulate precision errors, and long double is superfluous here, given that you only need seconds to microsecond resolution.
- Even if you fix the second roll-over issue, a problem remains if your start and end happen to be either side of midnight.

The following fixes all but the last of the issues above (solution to that later):

```
double getMedium( struct timeval x[][2] )
{
    unsigned long long diff = 0 ;
    int i ;
    for( i = 1; i < k.clientID; i++ )
    {
        unsigned long long start_usec = x[i][0].tv_usec * 1000000ULL + x[i][0].tv_usec ; 
        unsigned long long end_usec = x[i][1].tv_usec * 1000000ULL + x[i][1].tv_usec ; 
        diff += end_usec - start_usec ;
    }

    return diff / 1.0e6 ;
}
```

The resolution of the system clock used for `gettimeofday` is undefined, and may not provide microsecond resolution on your system.  If "DO A BUNCH OF STUFF" takes less time that the clock resolution you will get an answer of either zero or the clock resolution.

You can determine the resolution of the clock used by `gettimeofday` by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval t ;
    unsigned long long start_usec ;
    unsigned long long end_usec ;
    gettimeofday( &t, 0 ) ;
    start_usec = t.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + t.tv_usec ;

    do
    {
        gettimeofday( &t, 0 ) ;
        end_usec = t.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + t.tv_usec ;
    } while( start_usec == end_usec ) ;

    printf( "Clock resolution = %u microsecond(s)", end_usec - start_usec ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

You can of course simplify this code considerably by using the standard library `clock()` function, which will almost certainly have the same resolution as `gettimeofday()` (check the definition of CLOCKS_PER_SEC to be sure), but with none of the associated problems of second or day wraparound.

```
#include <time.h>

double getMedium( struct timeval x[][2] )
{
    time_t diff = 0 ;
    int i ;
    for( i = 1; i < k.clientID; i++ )
    {
        time_t start_time = clock() ; 
        time_t end_time = clock() ; 
        diff += end_time - start_time ;
    }

    return (diff * CLOCKS_PER_SEC) / 1.0e6 ;
}
```

You would do well in future to set the warning level on your compiler high and for warnings to be regarded as errors, `-Wall -Werror` in GCC or `\W4 \WX` in VC++ for example. You should also employ a source-level symbolic debugger to find problems in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't initilize dif to 0. There is garbage data in there...

```
double getMedium(struct timeval x[][2]){
  double diff =0;
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<k.clientID;i++){
      diff+= ((x[i][1].tv_usec )*0.0000001 -  (x[i][0].tv_usec)*0.0000001) ) ;
  }

  return diff;
}
```

Comment: @Noize this actually shouldn't even compile there is an extra ) on the diff line.

Comment: @Noize is there anything preventing you from doing `(x[i][1].tv_usec -  x[i][0].tv_usec)*0.0000001`? Mathematically they are the same, but computationally slightly more efficient. Also, a `printf` or two would very quiclky tell you where the problem lies if you think that `diff` is being computed wrong...

Comment: @nonsensickle:  Better yet accumulate and divide by 1.0e6 *outside* of the loop. 0.0000001 is incorrect in any case if the result is needed in seconds - one too many zeroes!  Use of a debugger would be better than `printf` debugging.